# How to load a XML file to drop down list in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have one aspx file(Demo.aspx) and one XML file(color.xml).
How to load XML file in drop down list?
How to mapping the my drop down list ID to that XML file(color.xml)

**Demo.aspx:**

```
<asp:Content ID="C2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder10" runat="server">
<tr>
    <td><asp:Label ID="L01" runat="server" Text="Colour :* " /></td>
    <td>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="V1" ControlToValidate="v1color" CssClass="error" InitialValue="" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server">
        Please select a colours <br />
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel3" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="v1color" DataTextField="ddl" Width="100%" TabIndex="16" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>                
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlasyRequest" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </td>
</tr>

</asp:Content>
```

**color.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Items>
  <Item ddlText="None" />
  <Item ddlText="Natural - RED" />
  <Item ddlText="Natural - WHITE" />
  <Item ddlText="Natural - BLUE" />
  <Item ddlText="Natural - YELLOW" />
  <Item ddlText="Natural - GREEN" />

</Items>
```

I am new to Dot net framework. Someone help me.

Comment: This will certainly help you: https://www.google.co.in/?q=asp.net%20dropdownlist%20xmldatasource

Answer (score 1):

use XmlDataSource. Load XmlDataSource with xml and set ddl DataSource to xmldatasource.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/494y92bs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**: Binding your dropdownlist with `XMLDataSource`.

Following changes requried in markup:

1. Add `XmlDataSource` in your markup
2. Provide physical path of your XML file in `DataFile`
3. Supply `XPath` query to look for `Item` elements in the Xml file.
4. Bind `DataSourceID` with your dropdownlist and give appropriate `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`

Example:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/XML/XMLFile1.xml" XPath="//Item"></asp:XmlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="v1color" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
                               DataTextField="ddlText" 
                               DataValueField="ddlText" 
                               Width="100%" TabIndex="16" runat="server" />
```

---

**Solution 2**: Loading XML in `XmlDocument` and build `ListItems`

You can follow these steps:

1. Load your XML in `XmlDocument`
2. For each xml node check for ddlText attribute and get its value
3. Make new `ListItem` from retrieved value and add to your `DropDownList`.

Something like that:

```
 XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
 xDocument.Load(@"YourXmlFile.xml");

 foreach (XmlNode node in xDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Item"))
 {
      v1color.Items.Add(new ListItem(node.Attributes["ddlText"].Value));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should work

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("c:\path\to\your\xml\your.xml");
this.DropDownList1.DataSource = doc.Root.Descendants().Select(i => i.Attribute("ddlText").Value);
this.DropDownList1.DataBind();
```